# Update error in postgres SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
CREATE TRIGGER INSERT_salesorderdetail
before insert on salesorderdetail
for each row 
UPDATE customer
set number_of_items=IFNULL(number_of_items,0)+1
where new.customerid=customer.customerid;
```

I have 2 tables salesorderdetail and customer and i want each time i inserts a new item in salesorderdetail to update my columne in customer the number_of_items but for some reason i get a syntax error in update.

Comment: Perhaps that is because you are using MySQL syntax to define a Postgres trigger.  Review the Postgres documentation.

Comment: How would it look like in postgres cause i cant find it another way

Comment: There are plenty of examples in the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_customer()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$

  -- update ur table here

        RETURN NULL;
    END; 
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION update_customer()
  OWNER TO db_name;
```

Now create trigger as:

```
CREATE TRIGGER INSERT_salesorderdetail
before insert on salesorderdetail
for each row execute procedure update_customer();
```